# Get document based on multiple criteria of embedded collection

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document, I need to search for multiple items from the embedded collection"items".

Here's an example of a single SKU

```
db.sku.findOne()
{
        "_id" : NumberLong(1192),
        "description" : "Uploaded via CSV",
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : NumberLong(2),
                        "category" : DBRef("category", NumberLong(1)),
                        "description" : "840 tag visual",
                        "name" : "840 Visual Mini Round",
                        "version" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                {
                        "_id" : NumberLong(7),
                        "category" : DBRef("category", NumberLong(2)),
                        "description" : "Maxi",
                        "name" : "Maxi",
                        "version" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                {
                        "_id" : NumberLong(11),
                        "category" : DBRef("category", NumberLong(3)),
                        "description" : "Button",
                        "name" : "Button",
                        "version" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                {
                        "_id" : NumberLong(16),
                        "category" : DBRef("category", NumberLong(4)),
                        "customizationFields" : [
                                {
                                        "_class" : "CustomizationField",
                                        "_id" : NumberLong(1),
                                        "displayText" : "Custom Print 1",
                                        "fieldName" : "customPrint1",
                                        "listOrder" : 1,
                                        "maxInputLength" : 12,
                                        "required" : false,
                                        "version" : NumberLong(0)
                                },
                                {
                                        "_class" : "CustomizationField",
                                        "_id" : NumberLong(2),
                                        "displayText" : "Custom Print 2",
                                        "fieldName" : "customPrint2",
                                        "listOrder" : 2,
                                        "maxInputLength" : 17,
                                        "required" : false,
                                        "version" : NumberLong(0)
                                }
                        ],
                        "description" : "2 custom lines of farm print",
                        "name" : "Custom 2",
                        "version" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                {
                        "_id" : NumberLong(20),
                        "category" : DBRef("category", NumberLong(5)),
                        "description" : "Color Red",
                        "name" : "Red",
                        "version" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        ],
        "skuCode" : "NF-USDA-XC2/SM-BC-R",
        "version" : 0,
        "webCowOptions" : "840miniwithcust2"
}
```

There are repeat items.id throughout the embedded collection. Each Sku is made up of multiple items, all combinations are unique, but one item will be part of many Skus.

I'm struggling with the query structure to get what I'm looking for.

Here are a few things I have tried:

```
db.sku.find({'items._id':2},{'items._id':7})
```

That one only returns items with the id of 7

```
db.sku.find({items:{$all:[{_id:5}]}})
```

That one doesn't return anything, but it came up when looking for solutions. I found about it [in the MongoDB manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all)

Here's an example of a expected result:

```
sku:{ "_id" : NumberLong(1013),
 "items" : [ { "_id" : NumberLong(5) }, 
 { "_id" : NumberLong(7) }, 
 { "_id" : NumberLong(12) }, 
 { "_id" : NumberLong(16) },
 { "_id" :NumberLong(2) } ] },
 sku:
{ "_id" : NumberLong(1014), 
"items" : [ { "_id" : NumberLong(5) },
 { "_id" : NumberLong(7) }, 
 { "_id" : NumberLong(2) }, 
 { "_id" : NumberLong(16) },
 { "_id" :NumberLong(24) } ] },
 sku:
{ "_id" : NumberLong(1015),
 "items" : [ { "_id" : NumberLong(5) },
 { "_id" : NumberLong(7) },
 { "_id" : NumberLong(12) }, 
 { "_id" : NumberLong(2) }, 
 { "_id" :NumberLong(5) } ] }
```

Each Sku that comes back has both a item of id:7, and id:2, with any other items they have.

To further clarify, my purpose is to determine how many remaining combinations exist after entering the first couple of items.

Basically a customer will start specifying items, and we'll weed it down to the remaining valid combinations. So `Sku.items[0].id=5` can only be combined with `items[1].id=7 or items[1].id=10` …. Then `items[1].id=7` can only be combined with `items[2].id=20` … and so forth

The goal was to simplify my rules for purchase, and drive it all from the Sku codes. I don't know if I dug a deeper hole instead.

Thank you,

Comment: Updated the question with more information.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? I want to return a list of Sku, and their embedded Items list. But yes, I only want the Id's from the embedded Sku.items

Comment: I would want unique ID's of items only. But I think that part will be simple, once I have the correct list to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**aggregation pipelines**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline)

```
db.sku.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$sku.items"},
    {"$group":  {"_id": "$_id", "items": {"$addToSet":{"_id": "$items._id"}}}},
    {"$match": {"items._id": {$all:[2,7]}}}
])
```

Comment: This looks good, but I ran the query and I received no results.

Comment: Does it matter that the Sku's have additional items, other than just 7 and 2?

Comment: Ok. Yeah, that's the whole PITA part of this. I won't initially have all the items, but I need to start narrowing the list down, to prevent orders that will not match. Basically there 2000 permutations of item combinations, only 625 are valid. So based on initial item selections, there's way less items available for subsequent selections. I was using the SKu's as my rules logic, maybe that's a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

On the part of extracting the `sku` with item IDs 2 and 7, when I recall correctly, you have to use `$elemMatch`:

```
db.sku.find({'items' :{ '$all' :[{ '$elemMatch':{ '_id'  : 2 }},{'$elemMatch':  { '_id' : 7 }}]}} )
```

which selects all `sku` where there is each an `item` with `_id` 2 and 7.

Comment: That returns what looks like solid data to me. I want to see what @Michael9 's aggregate function will do, since that might save me another step. 

But, this answer is very helpful nonetheless.

Comment: I edited the answer to fix a mismatch of curly braces, but otherwise it's great.